# Unable to get footer occupy the rest of the screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap without any modification. The layout is pretty simple. I've a top navbar. Then the main container. And in the end, I've a footer. Something like:

```
<head>
 <style>
      body {
        padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
    background-color: #ECECEC;
      }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    // navbar elements
    </div> <!-- end of class navbar -->

    <div class="container">
    // fluid-row class with two column structure
    </div> <!-- end of class container -->

    <div class="footer">
        <div class="container"> <!-- using container to left-align footer to the main content -->
        // some content
     </div> <!-- end of class footer -->
</body>
```

There are two things that am not able to do.

1) Whenever there's less content in the main container class, I need the footer to be aligned at the bottom of the screen. I tried min-height:100% but am doing something wrong.

2) I need the footer to have a different background color and footer should occupy the rest of the screen once the main container ends. The footer can have a minimum height or take the height as per the content inside the footer.

```
.footer {
height:80px;
margin-top:-80px;
position:relative;
clear:both;
padding-top:20px;
background-color:#F4F4F4;
border-top:1px solid #ddd;
clear:both;
}
```

What's going on here?

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m7dkt/13/

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick for you: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/ru2BD/

Instead of trying to figure out how to color the footer and have it extend to the bottom of the page, set the body color as what you need for the footer colour, then colour the content area between the header and the footer.

```
body {
background-color: #F4F4F4; /*same as footer color */
}

/* don't need to explicitly set footer colour now, it's set above */  

/* .footer {
background-color:#F4F4F4;   
}   */  

/* wrap page content and set the background colour */  

#wrapper{       
padding-top:10px;
background-color:#ECECEC;
}
```

**Update**

If I understand you correctly you also want the footer text to be aligned to the bottom of the window. See how this looks:
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/D7YXP/

It's a combination of the technique above with a sticky footer.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't solve problem 1 of footer going all the way to the bottom of the screen if the container has less content. If container has more content than the height of the screen, then the footer should just show after the content finishes at the bottom. How to make it work?

Comment: See update above to force footer text to the bottom of the window

Answer (score 0):

I used this trick: I hope it will be useful for you.

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
   <div id="clearfooter"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#clearfooter {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
}

#wrap{
    padding-bottom:69px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#footer{
    width:100%;
    height:69px;
    background:#8dc63f;
    overflow:hidden;
    clear:both;
    color:#FFF;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    opacity:0.9;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But this creates a sticky footer. I want the footer to show towards the end if the main container has less content. Otherwise, footer should show at its normal place, below the container. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the css below to your css:

```
html, body, #wrapper{
    height:100%;
}
```